# Which File Explorer "Details" can be set from a c# Assembly?

Tags: c#, windows, attributes, .net-assembly, microsoft-file-explorer

File Explorer offers a vast array of possible details to show.  Which ones can be set from within a c# assembly?
I am aware of:

- "**Company**" from the AssemblyCompany Attribute
- "**Copyright**" from the AssemblyCopyright Attribute
- "**File description**" from the AssemblyTitle Attribute
- "**File version**" from the AssemblyFileVersion Attribute (or the AssemblyVersion Attribute if AssemblyFileVersion is not set)
- "**Legal trademarks**" from the AssemblyTrademark Attribute
- "**Product name**" from the AssemblyProduct Attribute
- "**Product version**" from the AssemblyInformationalVersion Attribute (or the AssemblyVersion Attribute if AssemblyInformationalVersion is not set)

Are there any others that can be set either as Assembly Attributes or using some other mechanism?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/set-attributes#informational-attributes

Answer (score 0):

The properties of a file comes from basic filesystem properties (size, date/time, etc.) and from [specialized property handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/property-system-developer-s-guide).

The properties you listed come from the [version information resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/version-information) in PE files. While the version resource supports arbitrary string/value pairs, Windows is only going to expose the "standard" entries as properties.